# Why do we use zu Hause when it's das Haus?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In sentences

- Ich bin zu Hause.
- Ich gehe nach Hause.

why do we use *Hause* instead of *Haus*? It is *das Haus*, isn't it? In addition, why don't we say

- Ich gehe zum Haus(e).

as the preposition *zu* binds to **dative**?

Comment: I do not ask about the "e" at the end, but about "zu" instead of "zum"

Comment: You do. Not in the headline, but in the body.

Comment: OK :-) I did ask. But in different meaning, than the suggested answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays, the word *Haus* has two distinct broad meanings that in English are captured by the words *house* and *home*, respectively.

*Haus* in the sense of *house* refers to the building. Here, the dative and the accusative case are typically used without *-e* in contemporary German.

- Ich bin im Haus.

   (I am in the house.)
- Ich gehe zum Haus.

   (I walk to the house.)
- Ich gehe ins Haus.

   (I go into the house.)

*Haus(e)* in the sense of *home* refers figuratively to the rooms someone is living in. Here, the *-e* in dative and accusative case is a remnant from the past.

- Ich bin zu Haus(e).

   (I am at home.)
- Ich gehe zu Haus(e) herum.

   (I walk around at home).
- Ich gehe nach Haus(e).

   (I go home.)

Notice also that the adverb *zu Hause* can be written as one word: [*zuhause*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zuhause). Since the Orthogrtaphic Reform 2004/2006 both spellings are [equally valid](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/zuhause.shtml). Nominalizing the adverb results in a noun, [*Zuhause*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zuhause), that must be capitalized as such:

> Sie hat ein neues *Zuhause*.
>   
>  (She has a new home.)

Comment: Ich verstehe den Runterwähli bei der Antwort auch nicht. Hier hast du ein Hochwähli. Ich finde deine Antwort korrekt und besser, da es die ursprüngliche Frage eindeutig beantwortet.

Comment: "Runterwähli" ist sehr süß, muss ich mir merken. Ist das dialektal inspiriert?

Comment: Can you also add a bit about the use of Zuhause as a word - I've seen it used to mean "home" in nominative / accusative. (In a phrase like "Ein Tierheim ist ein Ort, wo Tiere leben, die kein Zuhause haben.")

Comment: @SassaNF, I added some words about the adverb *zuhause* and the noun *Zuhause*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Good answer. Of note is the regional variation of 'zu Hause'/'nach Hause' and 'daheim'/'heim'.

Comment: @NiklasE. Es gibt Leute, die der Ansicht sind, wenn eine Frage schlecht oder off-topic oder - wie in diesem Fall - ein Duplikat ist, solle man gefälligst keine Antwort schreiben, wer dennoch antwortet, bekommt ein downvote reingedrückt. Da sowohl die Frage als auch jede der beiden Antworten (zum jetzigen Zeitpunkt!) exakt 1 downvote hat, liegt die Vermutung nahe, dass hier jemand mit einer solchen Einstellung am Werke war.

Comment: @phipsgabler *"Runterwähli" ist sehr süß, muss ich mir merken. Ist das dialektal inspiriert?* - für mich klingt es jedenfalls sehr schweizerisch.

Comment: Schon irgendwie, aber nicht eindeutig. Er erinnert mich zu sehr an andere Ausdrücke Hermes Phettbergs "Heimhelfi" (und der ist eindeutig OÖ/NÖ zuzuordnen), oder ein (glaube ich) allgemein gebrauchtere "Verhüterli".  Ich muss wohl eine Frage dazu stellen.

Answer (score 2):

The word "Hause" is basically a remnant of the past German dialect. In that old Dialect, which you can read in some older Books like Goethes Iphigenie auf Tauris: "O süße Stimme! Vielwillkommener Ton der Muttersprache in einem fremden Lande!". Today you wouldn't say "Lande", you would simply say "Land". Back then it would be normal to say things like "zu Fuße", instead of "zu Fuß" and "zu Pfred(e)" instead of "mit dem Pferd". Somehow this didn't fully change for "zu Hause". although "zu Haus" is definetly used in normal conversation, I belive its still considered an abbreviation in writing. Dont know though.

As for the dative, "Ich gehe zum Hause" would just sound like the "old german" I described above. With that old dialect, it would not be wrong. Today we would say "Ich gehe zum Haus".

Comment: Thanks, and what about the dative ? Shouldn't it be zum ?

Comment: @John Ronald I edited the answer